# PHP redirect doesn't work with IF/ELSE that checks for REQUEST_METHOD

Tags: php

I have this sort of form:

```
<form action="/folder/" method="POST" target="_blank">
<input name="hello" type="hidden" value="something"  />
```

Inside the directory `/folder/`, I have an `index.php` that handles the form, and includes a redirect.

It worked well until I've inserted an IF/ELSE condition which checks whether the user actually got to `index.php` by submitting the form, and then the redirect would work; otherwise, if the user just typed the url: `http://mydomain.com/folder/`, I want him to see an error message, and so this is the code of `/folder/index.php`:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
?>
    <p>Error: You didn't come here by clicking the form.</p>
<?php
    } else {
?>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['hello']));

switch ($_POST['hello']) {

    case "1":
        $url = "http://destination1.com";
        break;

    case "2":
        $url = "http://destination2.com";
        break;

    default:
        $url = "other";
}

header( "refresh:3;url=$url" );

?>  
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Refershing page to: <?php echo $url; ?>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    }
?>
```

The page does not make the redirection, what is wrong?

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['hello']));` - that never gonna work, as semicolon at the end makes this a non-op.

Comment: I don't know why, but this part actually works well, as it echoes the URL just fine...

Comment: I would suggest that you start by reading a php tutorial.

Comment: @YannSagon I'm afraid I don't have time for broad tutorials, as I'm not a programmer, just using PHP occasionaly

Comment: @YannSagon You aren't contributing a lot with that comment.

Comment: Read the [php header() function documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

**Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.**

Comment: @TomKriek Yes you are right, but since in this short code there is a lot of errors/misconception, a good php tutorial would be a good approach.

Comment: @YannSagon You told him in a condescending tone. I'm ending these comments prevent further off-topic discussions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have whitespace in your output, which triggers output mode and disables any further header() calls:

```
    } else {
?>
     <---whitespace here
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['hello']));
                          ^---also incorrect
```

The code should simply be

```
} else if (isset(...)) {
```

and note the change of `;` to `{`.

If you had been properly developing with `error_reporting` and `display_errors` enabled, you'd have seen the PHP warning message about headers already having been sent. Never EVER develop with them turned off. It's the equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalala can't hear you".

Comment: Thank! this sorted it out even without the colon change, should I change the colon the { and that's it, or also add }?
I'm writing this with Dreamweaver, what's error_reporting?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a mess

other than the syntax error others have pointed out, breaking a php tag in the middle of an if statement for a html tag is dodgy...

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
?>
    <p>Error: You didn't come here by clicking the form.</p>
<?php
    } else {
?>
```

use this..

```
<?php

   $string='';

   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
      $string = 'Error: You didn\'t come here by clicking the form.';}
   else {

      if(isset($_POST['hello'])){
         $string = 'Refershing page to: ';
         switch ($_POST['hello']) {
            case '1': $url = 'http://destination1.com'; break;
            case '2': $url = 'http://destination2.com'; break;
            default: $url = 'other';}
         $string.= $url;}

   header('refresh:3;url='.$url);}

?>

<html>

<head></head>

<body>
   <?php echo '<p>'.$string.'</p>'; ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, though what do I do If I need the string to be a whole block of HTML, that would contain PHP variables as well? e.g, if there's an error, I want a `<DIV>Error, you won't go to <?php echo $var?></DIV>` as the string

Comment: a fullstop joins variables and strings..`echo '<p>'.$string.'</p>'`

Comment: $string = `'<div>Error, you won't go to '.$var.'</div>';`

Comment: if you want to add to a string use '.=' `$string = 'Refershing page to: '; $string.= $url;`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
?>
    <p>Error: You didn't come here by clicking the form.</p>
<?php
    } else {
?>

<?php
```

you are likely sending the headers already between else and the php tag. you dont need to close and open the php tags here.

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
?>
    <p>Error: You didn't come here by clicking the form.</p>
<?php
    } else {
 if(....
```

EDIT:

having a p tag before the doctype doesnt even make sense. You should save the error into a $error variable and display it in the html 'template' with `<?=$error?>` instead of closing and opening tags everywhere in your script.

Comment: Thanks, is there an example for how to do this? wouldn't that require adding another else/if? or moving it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this

```
if(isset($_POST['hello'])) {

switch ($_POST['hello']) {

case "1":
    $url = "http://destination1.com";
    break;

case "2":
    $url = "http://destination2.com";
    break;

default:
    $url = "other";
}

header( "refresh:3;url=$url" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your if statement has a syntax error. This:

```
if(isset($_POST['hello']));
```

Should be:

```
if(isset($_POST['hello'])){
```

And you also need one more closing bracket after the switch:

```
        $url = "other";
    }
header( "refresh:3;url=$url" );
}
```